# grails enum type validation not working as expected

Tags: grails, enums

I have a unit test that is failing on a constraint violation, where it should not be.  I'm testing if valid enums are set as variables of a domain class.

My Enum:

```
public enum GenderPreference {
    M('Male'),
    F('Female'),
    A('Any')

    final String value

    GenderPreference(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }
    public String toString() {
        value
    }
    public String getKey() {
        name()
    }
    public String getValue() {
        value
    }
}
```

My domain:

```
class Profile {
    GenderPreference genderPreference

    static constraints = {
        genderPreference (blank:true, nullable:true)
    }
}
```

My unit test:

works fine:

```
def instance = new Profile(genderPreference: GenderPreference.M)
assertTrue instance.validate(['genderPreference'])
```

this should fail but does not.  QQQ is not a valid enum

```
instance = new Profile(genderPreference: 'QQQ')
assertFalse instance.validate(['genderPreference'])
```

I'm using grails 2.2.4.  I think in older versions there was something else that had to be added to the domain constraints for enums, but I thought this should work.  What's missing?

Comment: I just copied your code, tested it and everything worked as expected. Do you really mean that the second test should fail or just that the validation should fail?

Answer (score 7):

You can use inList to add constraints to your enum

```
static constraints = {
    genderPreference blank:true, nullable:true,
                     inList: GenderPreference.values() as List
}
```

Comment: While that works, it means I have to duplicate all of the values for every enum class I have.  Some have 10 or 15 entries, and rather than listing them all in the constraint there has to be a cleaner way.