# enum validation succeeds but should fail

Tags: grails

In my unit test under grails 2.2.4 I'm attempting to pass in an invalid enum to see if it gets rejected.  It does not.

Here is my enum:

```
public enum CertificationStatus {
    N("No"),
    Y("Yes - Unverified"),
    V("Yes - Verified")

    final String value

    CertificationStatus(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }
    public String toString() {
        value
    }
    public String getKey() {
        name()
    }
    public String getValue() {
        value
    }
}
```

Here is my domain:

```
class Profile
    CertificationStatus certFosterCertified
static constraints = {
        certFosterCertified(blank: true, nullable: true)
}
```

Here is the unit test:

```
instance = new Profile(certFosterCertified: '#')
assertFalse instance.validate(['certFosterCertified'])
assertNotNull instance.errors.getFieldError('certFosterCertified')
```

The instance.validate returns true, but I'm passing in an invalid value for the enum in the Profile constructor ('#').  Shouldn't the validate fail because of the invalid enum?  The enum is setup with only Y,N, and V as valid values.  I didn't think I had to set those in the constraint because the field is defined as an enum.

Comment: The only constraints you have for your enum is `bank:true` and `nullable:true`. To add constraint you can follow the suggestion on your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912983/grails-enum-type-validation-not-working-as-expected).

Comment: Hopefully in a few weeks when I run into this again I won't ask the same question a third time.  What I found is the inList is completely ignored during the validation of an enum.  If an invalid value is assigned as an enum, the validation test will pass, but the value will not get assigned to the enum field (it will remain null).  So the test is to check for a success, then test that the field is null and the errors are null when assigning an invalid value.

Comment: create a sample project with test cases, I will be glad to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

With the constructor you set the value of `certBackgroundCheck` to `#`.

However, in your domain class your enum is named `certFosterCertified`. So `certFosterCertified` should be `null`, because it isn't initialized. According to the constraints `null` is a valid state (`nullable: true`).

Maybe you just need to change `certBackgroundCheck` to `certFosterCertified`?

Comment: Sorry, the code sample was not correct and listed the incorrect test.  I've updated it now.